# Я пытаюсь воспользоваться API OpenWeather но выдает ошибку

Tags: reactjs, api

Я использую API OpenWeather, погода на текущий момент и все работает, но когда я пытаюсь воспользоваться API погода на 30 дней но выдают ошибку
GET [https://pro.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/climate?lat=35&lon=139&appid=699a32a6da04fd9ad1d72a9df5226b4d}](https://pro.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/climate?lat=35&lon=139&appid=699a32a6da04fd9ad1d72a9df5226b4d%7D) 401 (Unauthorized)

пробовал создать новый ключ но не помогло

Comment: А вы заплатили? Эти данные вообще-то не входят в бесплатный пакет